# s3cmd sync not working from php system() while from shell it is

Tags: php, shell, system, s3cmd

Im trying to run a .sh script that contains "s3cmd sync.." command and it is not working.
When running the same sh from shell prompt it works perfect.
It seems that the execute permissions for s3cmd are insufficient when running from php system / shell_exec commands.

note : ( when running another .sh script from system() function that uses mysqladmin util , it works fine.)

Any ideas?
Thanks